# Is LocalDateTimeDeserializer from jsr310 deserializing zulu dates correctly?

Tags: java, spring, angular, datetime, jackson

I have an angular/spring boot application, on client side I'm using a primeng calendar input component, which takes the local date and converts it to UTC zoned date-time. I then send this date to a REST Controller and it's deserialized using `LocalDateTimeDeserializer`. The problem is, it just takes the date as-is, without actually caring about the server time-zone (so UTC datetime becomes local datetime).

I looked into the source code and here's the responsible snippet:

```
if (string.endsWith("Z")) {
    return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.parse(string), ZoneOffset.UTC);
}
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
if (string.endsWith("Z")) {
    return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.parse(string), ZoneOffset.of(ZoneId.systemDefault().getId()));
}
```

Or something similar?

Or is there something I'm not getting about the whole concept of LocalDateTime/Timezones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's doing the right thing IMO.

A `LocalDateTime` isn't "local to the server", it's "not in any specific time zone". If you've got a text value which indicates a date/time and *any* sort of time zone indicator (e.g. an offset from UTC or a time zone ID) then the most appropriate conversion to `LocalDateTime` would be to just ignore the offset/ID. So for example, take:

```
2017-07-18T12:04:00+01:00
```

That's a `LocalDateTime` of 2017-07-18T12:04:00, with a UTC offset of +1. So I'd expect that parsing it to a `LocalDateTime`, would give a result of 2017-07-18T12:04:00.

I would personally try not to this to start with though: parse the textual data into the most appropriate kind of value, then change to a different kind of value in whatever way you want. So if your input text always *does* have a UTC offset (potentially using `Z` for 0), then parse it as an `OffsetDateTime`, then *you* decide how you want to convert that to a `LocalDateTime`, and your code will be much clearer.

Basically, separate "change representation from text to in-memory" and "change what's being represented" into distinct operations.

Comment: That answers my question. I obviously misunderstood the concept of LocalDateTime.

Answer (score 1):

DateTime ending with `Z` is a standard way to denote **Zulu** time zone, which is another name for **UTC** time zone, so the original snippet is correct.